# Lost system icons

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, macbook-pro-retina

I got an issue on my macbook pro retina 15".
Brand new that I bought a month ago.
Just updated it with 10.8.4
And now I lost all systems icons in finder, safari, app store and so on.

I spent some hours to search and try some solutions, but nothing resolved my issue.

Here are some screenshots.

Thanks !

Update : I tried with another user, and icons are here, so it's related to my curent user

[image: Finder]
[image: Safari]
[image: App Store]

Comment: Do you have a `colored.icon.plist` in any of your Libraries?

Comment: No colored.icon.plist

Answer (score 1):

I just resolved my issue by reinstalling the combo 10.8.4

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1659

Answer (score 0):

Answers to these questions suggest starting up in safe mode once:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69433
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71419

I had a similar issue in an earlier version of 10.8, but it went away after I did an upgrade install from the recovery partition. (See http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763.)